# filename not valid when i write it with pyautogui

Tags: python, windows, pyautogui

I want to upload a file to a website

```
try:
    pk=browser.find_elements_by_class_name('fileupload')[0].click()

except:
    print("not working")
    browser.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('fileupload')[0].click();")
    time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.write("'C:/Users/SOMEN/Downloads/book.pdf'")
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

this is my code to upload file this works fine.
but when the windows file opener opens, my pyautogui write it to the search box but this is the problem windows says this filename is not valid hy please help me
[this the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fokm9.png)

[this the file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCV0m.png)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which is causing error is `path` lets make it correct with some discussion :

**1.** First you passed a `singly quoted path` try to avoid it and

**Update :**

```
pyautogui.write("'C:/Users/SOMEN/Downloads/book.pdf'")
```

**To :**

Either backslash escape the backslash:

```
pyautogui.write("C:\\Users\\SOMEN\\Downloads\\book.pdf")
```

Or use raw strings so backslashes aren't processed:

```
pyautogui.write(r"C:\Users\SOMEN\Downloads\book.pdf")
```

Comment: i used all but no hope

Comment: Are you still getting same error if yes please check file path by yourself by going into file location and let me know

Comment: please add that file location photo by going through `C` directory not directly through `Downloads` Folder

Comment: this is a strange problem

Comment: please check i added that photo